# How to call qml function from html side

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to invoke form HTML a *someFoo("someStr")* function which is located in QML as follows:

**QML**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWebEngine 1.0
import QtWebChannel 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    QtObject {
        id: myQmlObj

        WebChannel.id: "myQmlObj";

        function someFoo(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    }

    WebEngineView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "myHtml.html"

        WebChannel {
           id: webChannel
           registeredObjects: [myQmlObj]
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
        var myQmlObj = channel.objects.myQmlObj;
        myQmlObj.someFoo("blabla");
    });
</script>
```

**.pro** file includes

```
QT += core gui network webenginewidgets webchannel
```

but when I try it I get the following error:

> js: Uncaught ReferenceError: qt is not defined

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong? I am using Qt 5.9.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867334/how-to-pass-value-from-qml-to-javascript-in-qwebengineview/43885742#43885742). You just need to call QML function from Qt Object of QML

Comment: That was very helpful, now it works thanks a lot !