# How to use QML - QWebView in Android

Tags: android, qt, qml, qwebview

I want to deploy one YouTube application in Android. But it only works on my computer, and it does not work on Android. It does not load any video.
The problem is only with the QWebView. I used a code similar to this: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitqml-youtubeview-example.html

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Qt Documentations:

> **Qt WebEngine is not available on mobile platforms**

While

> **Qt WebView is actually useful for mobile platforms!** .. as [stated by Qt Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html)

You can use `QwebView` with `Android` , This should be possible with `Qt5.x`, as follow:

Configure project for Android kit and add `QT += webview` to your `.pro` file.

In `main.cpp`, **it's important to call** `QtWebView::initialize()` right after creating the `QGuiApplication`:

```
#include <QtWebView>
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QtWebView::initialize();
```

Now ready to use at qml side:

```
import QtWebView 1.1

WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "http://some/url/"
        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.errorString)
                console.error(loadRequest.errorString);
        }
    }
```

Check [Qt MiniBrowser Exmaple](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-minibrowser-example.html) for QwebView with `Android`.

Comment: @Carlos Duarte, Note that the first answer I think confused you ... the fact is that it is the the opposite. Qt `WebEngineView` works only on Qt for MSVS/Chromium .. while `QwebView` does work on Android, Check [Qt WebView Qt5.10](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Qt5. You should use WebEngineView, QWebView will not work on android.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtWebEngine 1.4

Item{
    id:root
    height: 500
    width:  500

   Rectangle{
      anchors.fill: parent
      color: "black"

      WebEngineView{
         id : webEnginView
         anchors.fill: parent
         url : https://www.google.com
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: for more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867334/how-to-pass-value-from-qml-to-javascript-in-qwebengineview)